# ? about Anatomy of a Double in general and in Delphi specifically

Tags: delphi, double

I understand that doubles have a sign (1 bit), exponent (11 bits) and fraction (52 bits) (according to Wikipedia anyway).

I have three questions.

1) How do I use these three parts to convert them to a number I can use (both the Integral and fractional parts)?

2) How are the three parts stored in a double within Delphi?

3) Once I know the integral and fractional parts, I'm really using them as a date and time with the date being the integral part being an offset in days and the fractional being an offset, I think, in milliseconds from midnight.  So really its two numbers I am trying to derive from the double, days and milliseconds.  The question is, is there a way to separate the two into ints?  that is, day offset into int (or longint) and milliseconds into another int (or longint) using standard math functions?

I found out earlier that hex representations of dates I have stored were indeed Delphi doubles (see below).  But I don't know how the double is represented

----------- answer to an earlier question --------------------------

Effectively these strings looks like the Hex representation for the Delphi TDatetime type which is an alias for the Double type (8 bytes), Where the integral part of the TDateTime value is the number of days that have passed since 12/30/1899 and the fractional part of the TDateTime value is fraction of a 24 hour day that has elapsed.

in Delphi you can parse such values using the HexToBin function like so

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils;

function Decode(const HexStr: AnsiString) : TDateTime;
begin
   Assert(Length(HexStr)=16, 'Lenght must be 16');
   HexToBin(PAnsiChar(HexStr), @Result, SizeOf(TDateTime));
end;

begin
  try
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('a297780add3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('5c6c320bdd3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('67b176e0dd3ee440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('38a7e155bc42e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d94ee458bc42e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d22af9134989dc40')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('d4fb7863c542e440')));
     Writeln(DateTimeToStr(Decode('e501c962c542e440')));
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

This will return

```
07-07-2013 21:46:50
07-07-2013 21:46:58
07-07-2013 22:24:27
07-08-2013 21:15:05
07-08-2013 21:15:37
01-01-1980 3:24:15
08-08-2013 4:02:29
08-08-2013 4:02:21
```

---

Comment: Why not use the DecodeDate and DecodeTime functions?

Comment: Or simply `DateUtils.DecodeDateTime`, which does both in one function call?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you are encoding your data as hex

Comment: I'm not, I just grabbed them out of a file with a hex editor.  I was really trying to understand the double format related to the date specifically and how I might use this to translate the double stored to a date/time in my own code.  Not in Delphi.  The questions posed were to increase my understanding of the method of and conversion from/to the double and find out if the double was stored in a standard way common amongst other languages.  I apologize for confusing the readers with the roundabout ? but I feared I would only get a part of what I needed had I posted anything less..

Comment: A double is a double. Same everywhere. Only possible variation is endianness.

Comment: Therin lies the rub.  I, being uninitiated to what endian scheme is used where, really was interested in the specifics of how Delphi stores it's date/time (more specifically its doubles) so I could decode it elsewhere.  I know I used the long way around, but actually the question got the answer needed so while some may not be happy with the process, I am.  Handy knowingit's the same everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Delphi double value is a standard IEEE754 double, using the standard representation. All languages do this for various reasons. Not least of which is that the underlying hardware operates of IEEE754 types.

You can pull a double value apart using the TDoubleHelper introduced in XE3. The documentation shows you how: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TDoubleHelper. For older Delphi versions you would use TDoubleRec instead.

Now, splitting the value into its significand and exponent will not help you. You want the integer part and the fractional part which are entirely different things. Get them using the standard functions Int() and Frac().

However, when you do this, you still won't have what you need. The fractional part is a floating point number between 0 and 1. That doesn't sound much like a number of milliseconds. So I believe that you do not yet fully understand this representation.

Perhaps what you have is nothing more than a TDateTime! In which case you use the standard functions from the RTL to decode it.

---

I've just read your earlier question. You are indeed on the wrong track. Read again the answer. Specifically:

> Where the integral part of the TDateTime
>   value is the number of days that have passed since
>   12/30/1899 and the fractional part of the TDateTime value is
>   fraction of a 24 hour day that has elapsed.

So, in your VB code, convert the hex string, or binary, whichever you have, into a double. Then get the integer part and the fractional part and you are done..

Comment: I don't need the two parts, only to understand the encoding so I know what I'm dealing with.  I was only ever interested in the integral/fractional values.  Perhaps not clear in my ? but thank you for the clarity in your answer.

Comment: Then all you need to know is that double precision has a standard representation

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what the relevant parts of a `TDateTime` contain.

The integral part (the part to the left of the decimal point) is the number of days that have elapsed since December 30, 1899, as you state. However, the fractional part (the part to the right of the decimal), is simply the decimal representation of the time that has passed since `00:00:00 0001` (the start of that day).

In other words,

```
0.25          12/30/1899 06:00:00 (6:00 AM)
0.5           12/30/1899 12:00:00 (noon)
0.75          12/30/1899 18:00:00 (6:00 PM)
```

The simplest way to work with Delphi's `TDateTime` and it's various parts is to let the RTL handle it for you. To separate out the individual portions of the time, use [`DecodeTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.DecodeTime). To retrieve the individual parts of a date, use [`DecodeDate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.DecodeDate) (both from the 'SysUtils' unit:

```
var
  Hr, Min, Sec: Word;
  Yr, Mon, Day: Word;  

  DecodeTime(Now, Hr, Min, Sec);
  DecodeDate(Now, Yr, Mon, Day);
```

To retrieve them all at once, use the `DateUtils` unit and [`DecodeDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.DateUtils.DecodeDateTime) instead:

```
  DecodeDateTime(Now, Yr, Mon, Day, Hr, Min, Sec);
```

If you really do want just the individual parts (the left and right sides of the decimal point), then as David says you just use [`Int`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Int) and [`Frac`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Frac)

Comment: I must confess to being confused by all this. I read the question that these data values are not TDateTime. But the asker does seem confused!

Comment: @David: It is confusing, but the overall question seems to be about not quite comprehending the relationship between a double and TDateTime (also having seen the other question). I had a few minutes. :-)

Comment: Oh I see. The second half of the Q was written by Rodrigo! If only the asker would read it!

Comment: @David: In looking at the poster's profile, I think I understand. It may be that he's trying to port something from a different language (COBOL, perhaps) and convert the stored data. I remembered the other question because I'd seen (and upvoted) Rodrigo's answer when he posted it (and reformatted the sample data while I was there so it was a little easier to read.)

Comment: Looks like VB from the comments there.

Comment: All, Thanks all for your comments.  Sorry I confused so many with what I asked but I've finally got my answer.  Two answers above actually constituted the answer I was looking for.  I am using another language to decode and use the integral and fractional parts separately so the questions I asked, while seeming confusing illicited the proper responses.  I'll be happy to discuss further if anyone is interested???  Again, all of the detail above is wonderful and I think that I finally have what I need.  Thanks so much!